# Pattern for cancelling a group of long-running goroutines

Tags: go, go-context

I would like to execute a set of long-running tasks in a loop and cancel all of them if any one fails. To do that I wrap each task in a Manager task that spawns off the actual long-running task and then goes back to waiting for the context to be cancelled due to an error in any other task in the loop.

My question is: "Does cancelling the individual Manager tasks also terminate the spawned off long-running task, given that the actual task has no reference to the cancellable context in the parent?"

The "working" code below should make my question clear. I understand that all instances of `readWithCancel` will return, but will each corresponding `readCSV` child terminate as a result.

Thanks as always

```
func main() {
    files := []string{"../data/file1.csv", "../data/file2.csv", "../data/file3.csv"}

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, file := range files {
        wg.Add(1)
        fileLocal := file
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if err := readWithCancel(ctx, fileLocal); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(fileLocal, err)
                cancel()
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func readWithCancel(ctx context.Context, file string) error {

    ch := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        ch <- readCSV(file)
    }()

    select {
    case err := <-ch:
        return err
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}

func readCSV(file string) error {

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("opening file %w", err)
    }

    cr := csv.NewReader(f)
    linenum := 0
    for {
        record, err := cr.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                return nil
            }
            return err
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", file, record)
        linenum++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no." Goroutines have no inherent relationship to each other (parent-child, etc.). A goroutine runs until its top-level function (the function specified in the `go` statement) terminates or the program terminates.

In the example code you provided, an error will result in the program terminating since canceling the context will cause the goroutines you're waiting for to terminate, causing `wg.Wait` to return. When that happens, the goroutines running `readCSV` will terminate with the program, but I don't think that's the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed that is not the solution I was looking for. The solution I want is for readCSV to terminate as soon as readWithCancel returns on <-ctx.Done and not when main completes. But I cannot think of a way to achieve this without passing ctx down to readCSV which again leads to spawning yet another goroutine so that ctx.Done can be read from

Comment: You can put a check for the context being canceled in the loop in your long running task without having to use a separate goroutine. Just use a `select` with an empty `default:` case and it won't block. (And you don't necessarily have to avoid creating goroutines – they're pretty cheap.)

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.